# How to generate a random number in a GUI?

Tags: java, parsing, user-interface, random, jpanel

I wrote a GUI program to guess a random number between 1 and 200.  When I run it, I can't get it to execute correctly.  I can guess the same number twice and sometimes it will say "too low", and sometime it say "too high".  I must have something out of order which I tried playing with, but I'm at a lost as to why this isn't working.  Here is my code:

```
    import java.util.Random;


    public class GuessPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

       protected Random random;
       protected int x;
       protected int n;

    public GuessPanel() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    **Generated Code**                    

    private void guessButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
         random = new Random();
         String s = userField.getText();
         int i = 200;
         x = random.nextInt(i);

         n = Integer.parseInt(s);

         if (x == n) 
         {
             answerLabel.setText("You guessed right!!!");
         } 
         else if (x > n)
         {
             answerLabel.setText("Your guess is too low, guess again");
         }  
         else if (x < n)
         {
             answerLabel.setText("Your guess is too high, guess again");
         }
}                                           
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel answerLabel;
private javax.swing.JButton guessButton;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JTextField userField;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: It's doing exactly what you are asking it do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're generating a new random number every time the "guess" button is pressed.  Either do that once when the GUI is loaded, or create a new button to reset the game and put your random number generation code there.

Comment: So would I do that in the constructor?

Comment: @user2272625 Yes, you could either do it in the constructor or in the `initComponents()` method, since it's called by your constructor.  I'd opt for doing it in `initComponents()`, since you could then call that method from a "reset" button handler.